# how to delete elasticsearch cross cluster search seed 5.5.1-1

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm running elasticsearch 5.5.1-1 and x-pack for monitoring.

Elasticsearch's documentation say's I should be able to add the following code to my elasticsearch.yml file for cross cluster search seeding:

```
search:
    remote:
        cluster_one: 
            seeds: 1.1.1.1:9300
        cluster_two: 
            seeds: 2.2.2.2:9300
```

Well that didn't work so I used the API as follows:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "search": {
      "remote": {
        "cluster_one": {
          "seeds": [
            "1.1.1.1:9300"
          ]
        },
        "cluster_two": {
          "seeds": [
            "2.2.2.2:9300"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That worked fine however I needed to delete cluster_one until it was upgraded to 5.5.1-1 which according to elasticsearch's docs say's should be completed as follows:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "search": {
      "remote": {
        "cluster_one": {
          "seeds": null 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It appears to takeas I get the acknowledgement:

```
    {
      "acknowledged" : true,
      "persistent" : { },
      "transient" : { }
    }
```

However if I curl the cluster settings I still see both nodes as follows:

```
   {
      "persistent" : {
        "search" : {
          "remote" : {
            "cluster_one" : {
              "seeds" : [
                "1.1.1.1:9300"
              ]
            },
            "cluster_two" : {
              "seeds" : [
                "2.2.2.2:9300"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "transient" : { }
    }
```

I wouldn't think I needed to restart elasticsearch after the API call but I tried that to no avail as well.

I also played with quoting/capitalizing null and got this return message which leads me to believe null is a valid value:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "json_parse_exception",
        "reason" : "Unrecognized token 'NULL': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@6053e99; line: 7, column: 25]"
      }
```

Comment: Figured out the resolution......
So I performed a downgrade/upgrade in hopes it would remove the seeds… it did not.

I performed an uninstall/reinstall with the same hope… it still did not remove the seeds.

I used locate to find every file in the file system and grepped each file for the IP and found the only file with the IP in it:

_/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0/\_state/global-14.st_

I rm’ed that file and restart elasticsearch and the seed settings were finally gone.

Answer (score 3):

Put the 'null' in squared brackets worked with my elasticsearch 5.5 installation:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "search": {
      "remote": {
        "cluster_one": {
          "seeds": [
            null 
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works for me as well.

Comment: I had 3 seeds, and this didn't work. I had to use this instead: `"seeds": [ null, null, null ]`, and it killed it for good